# How can i get only text in scrapy selector in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I hope you are doing well.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <s>Title:</s>
    De Aardappeleters
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Dimensions:</s>
    82 x 114 cm
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Media:</s>
    canvas
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Style:</s>
    Realism
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Date:</s>
    1885
  </li>              ______
  <li>                     |
    <s>Genre:</s>          | It is located on a page of the website here
    Modern                 |
  </li>              ______| 
</ul>
```

I have an HTML block☝ that I want to receive a text from **li**. But unfortunately, this **li** has no class or ID that I can select.This block is for a site.

```
  <li>
    <s>Genre:</s>
    Modern
  </li>
```

I want to select the genre list and get the text.

```
Modern
```

The main problem here is that this block is different on another page.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <s>Title:</s>
    De Aardappeleters
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Dimensions:</s>
    82 x 114 cm
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Media:</s>
    canvas
  </li>              ______
  <li>                     |
    <s>Genre:</s>          |And it is located here on another page.
    Modern                 |
  </li>              ______| 
  <li>
    <s>Style:</s>
    Realism
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Date:</s>
    1885
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
OriginalTagFind = layout.css('article ul li s::text').getall()
    
TitleOriginal = [tag.strip() for tag in OriginalTagFind if tag.startswith('Genre:')]
```

In my opinion, if I come to the place I have selected and print the text of the mother's list with Next Sibiling. is it possible؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a css selector you can use:

`'li:has(s):contains("Genre:")::text'`

With an xpath selector you can use:

`"//li[s[contains(text(), 'Genre')]]/text()"`

I have demonstrated using both with your example below:

```
In [1]: html = """<ul>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Title:</s>
   ...:     De Aardappeleters
   ...:   </li>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Dimensions:</s>
   ...:     82 x 114 cm
   ...:   </li>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Media:</s>
   ...:     canvas
   ...:   </li>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Style:</s>
   ...:     Realism
   ...:   </li>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Date:</s>
   ...:     188
   ...:   </li>
   ...:   <li>
   ...:     <s>Genre:</s>
   ...:     Modern
   ...:   </li>
   ...: </ul> """

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text=html)

In [3]: ''.join(selector.xpath("//li[s[contains(text(), 'Genre')]]/text()").getall()).strip()
Out[3]: 'Modern'

In [4]: ''.join(selector.css('li:has(s):contains("Genre:")::text').getall()).strip()
Out[4]: 'Modern'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following example and try:

```
genre = response.xpath('//li[s/text()="Genre:"]/text()').get()
```

if it contains extra spaces use strip() to remove spaces,

```
genre = response.xpath('//li[s/text()="Genre:"]/text()').get().strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this I am strictly against any kind of.. hardcoding field names in query as suggested in other answers.

```py
from parsel import Selector

html = '''
<ul>
  <li>
    <s>Title:</s>
    De Aardappeleters
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Dimensions:</s>
    82 x 114 cm
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Media:</s>
    canvas
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Style:</s>
    Realism
  </li>
  <li>
    <s>Date:</s>
    1885
  </li>              
  <li>              
    <s>Genre:</s>    
    Modern        
  </li>          
</ul> '''

response = Selector(html)

item = {}
for li in response.css('ul li'):
    item[li.css('s::text').get('')] = li.css('::text').getall()[-1].strip(' \n')

print(item)
```

In this case it is preferred to make cycle.. for each `li` tag. And inside `li` separately catch field name and it's text. With this approach You will be able to catch all field names/values.

Output from `print(item)`:

```
{
    'Title:': 'De Aardappeleters',
    'Dimensions:': '82 x 114 cm',
    'Media:': 'canvas',
    'Style:': 'Realism',
    'Date:': '1885',
    'Genre:': 'Modern'
}
```